# Access canvas outside prototype

Tags: javascript, canvas, meteor

I'd like to change the color of a code-based image on a HTML canvas everytime you hit a button. The code of the canvas/object is not my code. The problem is that I can't manage to change or even access the access outside the c.B. prototype and the color(); part. 
So in short:

- How can I access the canvas and the color of the image in another file (so outside the scope of the prototype and color function)?

This is the JS code of the button, where I want to access the canvas and color (code is based on Meteor).

```
Template.flowers.events({
 'click .click': function() {
   old = flowers.get()
   flowers.set(old + 1);
  }
});
```

This is a part of the code of the image (in another file). The HTML element has a canvas renderer, so that's what the getAttribute is for.  'h' is later on assigned to functions like performance.now(); for example

```
(function(z, h) {
   function colors(x) {
      this.element = x; //this refers to the image in the HTML
      this.B = x.getAttribute("colour") || "red"; //this refers to the current colour rendered in the HTML
      this.b = {
          background: "white",
      };
      switch (this.B) {
          case "pink":
              this.b.background = "pink";
              break;
     }

      this.createCanvas()

  c.W.prototype = {
      createCanvas: function() {
          this.element = h.createElement("canvas");
          this.element.className = "fill";
          this.ctx = this.element.getContext("2d");
          this.x.element.appendChild(this.element);

      },

     c.canvas =
      c.W;

     c.n = function(x) {
      this.x = x
     }; //after this follows: a c.n prototype{}

})(window, document);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You've unfortunately left out much of the code that would be required to actually answer this question. For example who calls `colors()`? Where is `h` defined? What is the data context `this` for `colors()`?

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code. There's a lot of code (over 500 lines), and there are a tons of assignments like this.a = this.c. It's a little hard to figure out what's necessary to post. Is it better to understand now?